# How to add the config in react-native-fs?

Tags: react-native, fs, react-native-fs

I installed `react-native-fs` and I followed through the document. I did all the configuration but at the last, they mentioned I should make the changes in `MainApplication.java` . But configuration is not the same as their document.

**react-native-fs ==> MainApplication.java**

```
import com.rnfs.RNFSPackage; // <------- add package

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
   // ...
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
        new MainReactPackage(), // <---- add comma
        new RNFSPackage() // <---------- add package
      );
    }
```

**My app ===> MainApplication.java**

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          return packages;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`react-native-fs` installation instructions were written long time ago when `autolinking` was not there(prior to React Native v0.60.0 release).

Firstly, if you are using React Native version 0.60.0+, then you do not have to perform any additional android and iOS(except the `pod install` for iOS) steps as described in the `Readme.md` of the package since `autolinking` will automatically handle the native configuration part.

But if you still want to manually link the library, then in your given android code in **MainApplication.java** file, you can add the `new RNFSPackage()` as shown in the code snippet below.

```js
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
          packages.add(new RNFSPackage()); //<== here
          return packages;
        }
```

Comment: I tried this not working

Comment: thanks, went back to delete all those from readme and it works great!